# PulseAudio/ Alsa problem - PulseAudio set s32le instead of s24le

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Card Xonar DX (192kHz 24bit max, works that way on Windows)

pacmd list-sinks:

```
sample spec: s32le 2ch 192000Hz
...
properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "24"
```

My PulseAudio config /etc/pulse/daemon.conf:

```
resample-method = soxr-vhq
avoid-resampling = true
default-sample-format = s24le
default-sample-rate = 192000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

Why Pulse cant use 24bit as output to ALSA? It did once but after I changed to 32 for testing it never come back to 24bit. Is there any way to set it back to 24bit? Now card is working properly(it shouldn't be).

Edit:
When I changed to s16le ALSA says its 16bit but when reverted to s24le its says 32bit...

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used pipewire, but it works on all servers if sound in Ubuntu or any other distro: use "S24_LE". Don't avoid the underscore. It's very important to do it because it doesn't adapt otherwise, and certainly use the double marks before and after it.

I was using this solution because my situation avoided using one sound card that doesn't support the 32-bit setup, so try that but restart your server too. Maybe a reboot is required in setting it up.